# How to do this in a single Cypher Query?

Tags: neo4j

So this is a very basic question. I am trying to make a cypher query that creates a node and connects it to multiple nodes.

As an example, let's say **I have a database with towns and cars**. I want to create a query that:

1. **creates people**, and
2. connects them with the **town they live in** and **any cars they may own**.

So here goes:

Here's one way I tried this query (I have WHERE clauses that specify which town and which cars, but to simplify):

```
MATCH (t: Town)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c: Car)
MERGE a = ((c) <-[:OWNS_CAR]- (p:Person {name: "John"}) -[:LIVES_IN]-> (t))
RETURN a
```

But this returns multiple people named John - one for each car he owns!

In two queries:

```
MATCH (t:Town)
MERGE a = ((p:Person {name: "John"}) -[:LIVES_IN]-> (t)) 


MATCH (p:Person {name: "John"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (c:Car)
MERGE a = ((p) -[:OWNS_CAR]-> (c))
```

This gives me the result I want, but I was wondering if I could do this in 1 query. I don't like the idea that I have to find John again! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It took me a bit to wrap my head around why `MERGE` sometimes creates duplicate nodes when I didn't intend that. [This article](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-how-merge-works/) helped me.

The basic insight is that it would be best to merge the `Person` node first before you match the towns and cars. That way you won't get a new `Person` node for each relationship pattern.

If `Person` nodes are uniquely identified by their `name` properties, a unique constraint would prevent you from creating duplicates even if you run a mistaken query.

If a person can have multiple cars and residences in multiple towns, you also want to avoid a cartesian product of cars and towns in your result set before you do the merge. Try using the table output in Neo4j Browser to see how many rows are getting returned before you do the `MERGE` to create relationships.

Here's how I would approach your query.

```
MERGE (p:Person {name:"John"})
WITH p
OPTIONAL MATCH (c:Car) 
WHERE c.licensePlate in ["xyz123", "999aaa"]
WITH p, COLLECT(c) as cars
OPTIONAL MATCH (t:Town) 
WHERE t.name in ["Lexington", "Concord"]
WITH p, cars, COLLECT(t) as towns
FOREACH(car in cars | MERGE (p)-[:OWNS]->(car))
FOREACH(town in towns | MERGE (p)-[:LIVES_IN]->(town))
RETURN p, towns, cars
```

Comment: Follow-up comment: 
This command works perfectly and creates only 1 John when executed in the Neo4j browser. However, it creates 2 Johns when I use it as a custom cypher query (as outlined here: https://neo4j.com/docs/spark/current/writing/#write-query) with the Neo4j spark connector :(

Comment: I suspect that you would be better off loading the nodes and relationships in separate steps. If you have indexes on the unique identifiers for the nodes, then finding the nodes again to add relationships after you have created the nodes should be extremely fast. You could use the label and relationship options with the Spark loader.